# Have an UserControl modified by another thread that the main thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

Currently, we have an application that display a lot of data into several charts with a high update rate(~100ms). To draw the charts, we use a library(Nevron).

Currently, the charts are created on the main thread, and we make an Invoke on the ChartControl for every of our action.

The issue is that now, the main thread is working as it maximum, since it has to draw a lot of differents charts.

My question is: Is there a way to make the drawing of every chart in a separate thread?

Is it possible to create the user controls in different thread and host them in the same windows(that is owned by a different parent) ?

Comment: You might be able to use a background worker and the report progress event to update the charts.

Comment: @Lidaranis I already have a background worker that give the new data to the chart, but time-consuming operation is to draw the chart.

Comment: Well, that all depends on what your library can do, doesn't it? If they allow rendering to some backsurface, you can easily render in multiple threads. If they only allow rendering to a user control, you're in trouble. It's *possible* to have multiple UI threads, but it's quite tricky (especially if you want the result in a single window :).

Answer (score 0):

You can draw frames in different threads to different bitmaps, and in main thread just draw these bitmaps

Comment: and concretely if I've a sub UserControl, how do I do this?